# Event which fires first and only one time when website starts in an asp.net c# website

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want an event which gets fired only once when my website launches for the first time...

Actually the situation is, I am creating an e-commerce website in asp.net, and i have created a cart table for storing the orders of clients.

So i want to empty that table the first time the website launches, **so the next user does not see the orders of the previous user...**

I tried the application_start and session_start event but both are being fired every time when any new page is opened... **I don't want to fire that event for every page.**

I am a beginner in asp.net.. any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance friends..

Comment: Also take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11932543/storing-items-for-a-basket-in-session-variables for info on how to store the basket in memory, unless theres a specific reason to store the basket in the database I wouldn't, store it in the session instead, and it will be new for every user / session they create.

Comment: I suggest you research how asp.net pipeline works, what http modules and handlers are and their role in the pipeline. It appears you lack the basics, but these are too much for question/answer format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are getting a bit confused here...

"So i want to empty that table the first time the website launches, so the next user does not see the orders of the previous user."

Application_Start should only fire when the site is first visited, it will not fire again for another user unless it is in a stopped state when they visit it.

If you are creating the table data in memory, then it will be new for every user, no need for Application_Start.

You could store the userid / session id in the cart table to, then only retrieve the basket for the correct user whenever they visit your site, or even better store them in a cookie so they can revisit your site before cookie expiration and still have their cart.

If Application_Start is firing everytime you visit a page then your IIS settings are a bit suspect.

Use the following function in the global.asax file...

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
}
```

[Taken from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29)...

"The **Application_Start** and Application_End methods are special methods that do not represent HttpApplication events. ASP.NET calls them once for the lifetime of the application domain, not for each HttpApplication instance."

Comment: Thanx for reply, can you tell me "_pagePath = Server.MapPath("~/Folder/Page.aspx");" what this line will do ?

Comment: Ok, i tried application_start but it is firing on each page.. what should i do ?

Comment: I think your functionality logic is a bit screwy so go look at some examples... e.g. take a look at http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5653/Generic-Shopping-Basket for some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Events of the [global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) file are what you are looking for. Perhaps [this techrepublic post](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/working-with-the-aspnet-globalasax-file/) could provide you some guidance on using the `Application_Init` and `Application_Start` events.

Hope I helped!